# How do I get row count using the NHibernate QueryOver api?

Tags: nhibernate, queryover, rowcount

I'm using the QueryOver api that is part of NHibernate 3.x.  I would like to get a row count, but the method I'm using returns all objects and then gets the count of the collection.  Is there a way to just return an integer/long value of the number of rows?

I'm currently using:

```
_session.QueryOver<MyObject>().Future().Count()
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

After a bit of playing around with the api, this will do it:

```
_session.QueryOver<MyObject>()
    .Select(Projections.RowCount())
    .FutureValue<int>()
    .Value
```

If you don't want to return it as a future, you can just get the `SingleOrDefault<int>()` instead.

Answer (score 37):

Another method

```
var count = Session.QueryOver<Employer>()
    .Where(x => x.EmployerIsActive)
    .RowCount();
```

Answer (score 8):

Another method:

```
int employerCount = session
  .QueryOver<Employer>()
  .Where(x => x.EmployerIsActive) // some condition if needed
  .Select(Projections.Count<Employer>(x => x.EmployerId))
  .SingleOrDefault<int>();
```

Answer (score 7):

Im using like this:

```
public int QuantidadeTitulosEmAtraso(Sacado s)
    {
        TituloDesconto titulo = null;
        Sacado sacado = null;

        var titulos =
                _session
                .QueryOver<TituloDesconto>(() => titulo)
                .JoinAlias(() => titulo.Sacado, () => sacado)
                .Where(() => sacado.Id == s.Id)
                .Where(() => titulo.Vencimento <= DateTime.Today)
                .RowCount();

    }
```