# Nhibernate QueryOver - Get Child Count for Pagination

Tags: c#, nhibernate, pagination, queryover

I am using Nhibernate 3.0 and need to implement paging onto a site.  Basically we have a ProductCategory which has a collection of Products associated with it. So far I have this which does work

```
var result = Session.QueryOver<TEntity>().TransformUsing(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity)
            .Where(category => category.CategoryId == criteria.CategoryId)
            .Fetch(category => category.Products).Eager
            .Take(pageSize)
            .Skip((pageIndex - 1)*pageSize)
            .Future<TEntity>();
```

This returns me the category I am requesting and the child products paged correctly based on the page size and page index passed in.

What I want to do now is actually get the total row count of the products, so for example, even though I am only returning 5 products for example, I need to know that there are 100 in total.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should do that with another query by going from the `Product` side and employing `.RowCount()`.

Something like this (if your `Product` has a `Category` property):

```
int count = session.QueryOver<Product>()
    .Where(x => x.Category.Id == categoryId)
    .RowCount();
```

Here you can find several more ways to get count: [How do I get row count using the NHibernate QueryOver api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489548/how-do-i-get-row-count-using-the-nhibernate-queryover-api)

Another blog post that might be helpful to you:
[NHibernate 3.0 QueryOver - Searching, and Paging at database level](http://random-monkey-wibblings.blogspot.com/2010/11/nhibernate-30-queryover-maximum-love.html)

Comment: Thanks Miroslav, that has done the trick, I will use the FutureValue method, so I only have 1 round trip to the db.